# Custom Control and Dependency Property Inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a custom control (MediaPlayer) that contains 2 other custom controls, a media player (Host) and a control bar (UI).

This control in itself is quite simple, it just binds the two together for display.

Now the first problem I got is that I couldn't set Host or UI properties from MediaPlayer, so I duplicated all properties relevant at design-time and linked them via binding. Is this the right away of achieving this? It's kind of clunky but it works.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MediaPlayerWpf}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MediaPlayerWpf}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_HostGrid" Margin="0,0,0,46">
                            <!--Filled by SetPlayerHost -->
                        </Grid>
                        <local:PlayerControls x:Name="PART_MediaUI" Height="46" Width="Auto"
                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" MouseFullscreen="{TemplateBinding MouseFullscreen}"
                                MousePause="{TemplateBinding MousePause}"
                                IsPlayPauseVisible="{Binding IsPlayPauseVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                IsStopVisible="{TemplateBinding IsStopVisible}"
                                IsLoopVisible="{TemplateBinding IsLoopVisible}"
                                IsVolumeVisible="{TemplateBinding IsVolumeVisible}"
                                IsSpeedVisible="{TemplateBinding IsSpeedVisible}"
                                IsSeekBarVisible="{TemplateBinding IsSeekBarVisible}"
                                PositionDisplay="{TemplateBinding PositionDisplay}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is a class for a generic media player. Then I have another Custom Control deriving from it that sets it to use a specific media player. (have one using MPV video player, and another one displaying a VapourSynth script output)

The derived class looks like this.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:VsMediaPlayer}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ui:MediaPlayerWpf}}" />
```

Now the problem is I want to expose Script and Path properties as dependency properties so they can be databound. I can't take exactly the same approach as above, so how can I do it? The Host the Path and Script will be bound to is created at run-time within OnApplyTemplate.

I'm a bit confused about how to make this one work, and I'm not sure the first code above is the best solution. Thanks for any guidance.

I guess one option is to copy the base style template instead of inheriting from it, and I could initiate the Host class there instead of at run-time. Any other option?

Edit: Host property is declared like this in my generic MediaPlayer class, but I couldn't find a way to set its sub-properties (Host.Source) from the designer.

```
public static DependencyProperty HostProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Host", typeof(PlayerBase), typeof(MediaPlayerWpf),
    new PropertyMetadata(null, OnHostChanged));
public PlayerBase Host { get => (PlayerBase)GetValue(HostProperty); set => SetValue(HostProperty, value); }
private static void OnHostChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    MediaPlayerWpf P = d as MediaPlayerWpf;
    if (e.OldValue != null)
        P.HostGrid.Children.Remove(e.OldValue as PlayerBase);
    if (e.NewValue != null) {
        P.HostGrid.Children.Add(e.NewValue as PlayerBase);
        P.TemplateUI.PlayerHost = e.NewValue as PlayerBase;
    }
}
```

Edit: this is the XAML code of MediaPlayer

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EmergenceGuardian.MediaPlayerUI">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MediaPlayerWpf}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MediaPlayerWpf}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_HostGrid" Margin="0,0,0,46"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            <local:PlayerControls x:Name="PART_MediaUI" Height="46" Width="Auto"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" MouseFullscreen="{TemplateBinding MouseFullscreen}"
                                    MousePause="{TemplateBinding MousePause}"
                                    IsPlayPauseVisible="{Binding IsPlayPauseVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                    IsStopVisible="{TemplateBinding IsStopVisible}"
                                    IsLoopVisible="{TemplateBinding IsLoopVisible}"
                                    IsVolumeVisible="{TemplateBinding IsVolumeVisible}"
                                    IsSpeedVisible="{TemplateBinding IsSpeedVisible}"
                                    IsSeekBarVisible="{TemplateBinding IsSeekBarVisible}"
                                    PositionDisplay="{TemplateBinding PositionDisplay}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Adding x:FieldModifier="public" to PART_MediaUI throws "The attribute FieldModifier does not exist in namespace"

SOLUTION!!! After working with a few attached properties, I finally understand how they work, and attached properties are indeed the right solution. This will allow me to set UIProperties.IsVolumeVisible on the parent class. I just need to repeat that code for every property.

```
public static class UIProperties {
    // IsVolumeVisible
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsVolumeVisibleProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsVolumeVisible", typeof(bool),
        typeof(UIProperties), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsVolumeVisibleChanged));
    public static bool GetIsVolumeVisible(DependencyObject obj) => (bool)obj.GetValue(IsVolumeVisibleProperty);
    public static void SetIsVolumeVisible(DependencyObject obj, bool value) => obj.SetValue(IsVolumeVisibleProperty, value);
    private static void OnIsVolumeVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (!(d is MediaPlayerWpf P))
            return;
        P.UI.IsVolumeVisible = (bool)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicating it is clunky, and it'll work; but you can just set that control type as a dependency property in itself and reference it directly. ```local:PlayerControls.MediaPlayer``` and ```local:PlayerControls.ControlBar``` for example.  Another option is to apply the public field modifier to the controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a partial solution. Instead of inheriting MediaPlayer from Control, I inherit from ContentControl.

In MediaPlayer Generic.xaml, I display the content like this right above the UI controls

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_HostGrid" Margin="0,0,0,46" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
```

Override property metadata to ensure content is of type PlayerBase and to pass the content reference to the UI control

```
static MediaPlayerWpf() {
    ContentProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MediaPlayerWpf), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(ContentChanged, CoerceContent));
}
public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    UI = TemplateUI;
    UI.PlayerHost = Content as PlayerBase;
}

private static void ContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    MediaPlayerWpf P = d as MediaPlayerWpf;
    if (P.TemplateUI != null)
        P.TemplateUI.PlayerHost = e.NewValue as PlayerBase;
}

private static object CoerceContent(DependencyObject d, object baseValue) {
    return baseValue as PlayerBase;
}
```

And then I can use it like this

```
<MediaPlayerUI:MediaPlayerWpf x:Name="Player" IsVolumeVisible="False" IsSpeedVisible="False" IsLoopVisible="False" PositionDisplay="Seconds">
    <VapourSynthUI:VsMediaPlayerHost x:Name="PlayerHost" />
</MediaPlayerUI:MediaPlayerWpf>
```

The advantage is that I no longer need to inherit from MediaPlayerWpf so there are less controls to manage.

However, I still need to duplicate UI properties to expose them to the designer, haven't found a way to access them in any other way.

Setting x:FieldModifier="public" in Generic.xaml results in "The attribute 'FieldModifier' does not exist in XML namespace"

UI is exposed as a dependency property like this. The designer allows to set UI="..." but not UI.IsVolumeVisible="false" nor recognizes < local:UI>. Is there a way to expose it from within a custom control?

```
public static DependencyPropertyKey UIPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("UI", typeof(PlayerControls), typeof(MediaPlayerWpf), new PropertyMetadata());
public static DependencyProperty UIProperty = UIPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
public PlayerControls UI { get => (PlayerControls)GetValue(UIProperty); private set => SetValue(UIPropertyKey, value); }
```

Comment: Yes, you can actually get it to work anyway you prefer and I believe design choices should be considered depending on what you choose to do.  That said, if you have all the DP's written to write directly to it there's nothing inherently wrong with that either but I still agree it's a bit overkill.  My only recommendation is to consider what you want to happen and how you want the control to be used / inherited ETC in your, and possibly any other, project(s).  Writing the control should follow SOLID principles in short so choose whatever helps you accomplish that goal the best.

Comment: I'm using this project to study proper WPF/MVVM design principles so I want to do it right. It's taking me forever to get it done because I'm studying so many aspects and getting stuck on many details like this one. I do want to access the child object from the designer (of a Custom Control, not User Control), but have yet to find the way to do so.

Answer (score -1):

I gave a comment above about how you could use a `DependencyProperty` and set it that type etc.  This is all good but may be overkill for what you need.  Just use the `x:FieldModifier="public"` to get what you're looking for.

Here's an example:

I make 3 user controls and have my `MainWindow`.  The user controls are `MainControl`, `SubControlA`, `SubControlB`.

In `MainControl` I first give the controls a logical name and then `FieldModifier` to public.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Question_Answer_WPF_App.MainControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Question_Answer_WPF_App"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:SubControlA x:Name="SubControlA" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
        <local:SubControlB x:Name="SubControlB" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Then I place that `MainControl` in my `MainWindow` and use it like so:

```
<Window x:Class="Question_Answer_WPF_App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Question_Answer_WPF_App"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800">

    <Grid>
        <local:MainControl>
            <local:SubControlA>
                <TextBlock Text="I'm in SubControlA" />
            </local:SubControlA>
        </local:MainControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Hope this helps.  The idea is you can also reference the `DependencyProperty`s from those controls also like `Visibility` etc. (or whatever you were using in yours in the question.)

This is just an example as I wouldn't recommend doing it this cheap.

---

Ok, to follow up the answer from your comments / questions below let me explain how it works a little deeper.  First, the `SubControlA` and `SubControlB` are just two empty `UserControls` that I made to have the example work.

In `xaml` anything between brackets gets initialized at that point.  We use the namespace / type name to target the property and whatever is between the brackets goes to the setter of that property.

Consider this `MainWindow`... All I do is place a custom `UserControl` in it and it looks like this in `xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="Question_Answer_WPF_App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Question_Answer_WPF_App"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800">

    <local:ExampleControl />

</Window>
```

…  and it looks like this in when ran

[image]

---

Now to see the custom `ExampleControl` because so far no big deal.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Question_Answer_WPF_App.ExampleControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:Media="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media;assembly=PresentationCore"
             xmlns:Windows="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationCore"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450"
             d:DesignWidth="800">
    <StackPanel>

        <Button Visibility="Visible"
                Height="50" 
                Background="Blue"
                Content="Button A"/>

        <Button>
            <Button.Visibility>
                <Windows:Visibility> Visible </Windows:Visibility>
            </Button.Visibility>
            <Button.Height>
                <System:Double> 50 </System:Double>
            </Button.Height>
            <Button.Background>
                <Media:SolidColorBrush>
                    <Media:SolidColorBrush.Color>
                        <Media:Color>
                            <Media:Color.R> 0 </Media:Color.R>
                            <Media:Color.G> 0 </Media:Color.G>
                            <Media:Color.B> 255 </Media:Color.B>
                            <Media:Color.A> 255 </Media:Color.A>
                        </Media:Color>
                    </Media:SolidColorBrush.Color>
                </Media:SolidColorBrush>
            </Button.Background>
            <Button.Content> Button B </Button.Content>
        </Button>

    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

In this `ExampleControl` I have two identical buttons, except one says *Button A* and the other *Button B*.

Notice how I referenced the properties in the first button via the properties name directly (which is mostly used) but I reference it by namespace / type for the second one.  They have the same results...

Also notice that I had to include the reference to the namespace for certain types like:

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:Media="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media;assembly=PresentationCore"
xmlns:Windows="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationCore"
```

`XAML` has a built in parser that takes the string you send and attempts to designate initialize it as the type needed for the property.  See how this works for enums (Visibility : System.Windows.Visibility), primitives (Height : System.Double), and unique objects like (Background : System.Windows.Media.Brush).

Also notice that `Background` being a `Brush` type can be of any type that derives from `Brush`.  In the example I use a `SolidColorBrush` which has a base of `Brush`.

However; I also take it a step further in the `Background`.  Notice that not only do I assign the `SolidColorBrush` but I assign the `Color` property of the `SolidColorBrush` as well.

Take your time to understand how the `xaml` is parsing and using these features and I believe it'll answer your question about how I'm referencing `SubControlA` and `SubControlB` from my `MainControl` at the beginning of this answer.

Comment: I was wondering how to access sub-properties from the designer and couldn't find the solution. I edited my question with the declaration of Host as a dependency property. Then in the derived class I want to replace Host property type (base-class type) with a derived-class data type. Did so with a regular property "public new VsMediaPlayerHost Host { }" but don't see how to do it as dependency property. Also PlayerBase, the base type for all media players, cannot use dependency properties because I must be able to override its properties to implement player features.

Comment: if I set x:FieldModifier="public" within Generic.xaml, I get "The attribute 'FieldModifier' does not exist in XML namespace". If I set UI as a dependency property (tried read-only and read-write) and try to access it, I get "The tag UI does not exist in namespace". Any other idea?

Comment: They both work and my example is a working WPF example.  Are you using WPF or UWP or Xamarin?  It's slightly different depending but I see WPF in your tags and it should work there.

Comment: Post the entire XAML view.  Maybe you're just missing the namespace I have in mine associated with x but that should be there by default.

Comment: A difference is you're using UserControl, not a custom control. That's a big difference.

Comment: I tried reproducing your sample, but what are controls SubControlA and SubControlB? There's some confusion between type name and instance name. If I try reference MainControl and then type <local: below it, it only gives me type names, not instance names. What happens if you have a UserControl with 2 instances of SubControlA?

Comment: @EtienneCharland  I'm going to update my answer explaining how ```xaml``` looks at controls and the difference between type and instance.  Standby...

Comment: @EtienneCharland  Ok, I've updated the answer only to include more explanation at the bottom about how ```xaml``` references types / instantiates them / gets the instantiated version.  I hope it helps clarify somethings.

Comment: Thanks. I was also thinking of the Slider's Thumb and how it works... but truth is it can't be accessed from the designer, I had to use code-behind to get to DragStarted//DragCompleted events. It looks like I can access child properties when defining the whole child object, but not set just one property of an already-set child object. This would allow me to implement a similar solution to what I posted below having it strongly-typed without inheriting from ContentControl. In my particular case it's working good enough, but this would allow setting more than 1 child objects.

Comment: You can manipulate the Slider also... as with most controls they use templates to define their layout and sometimes provide a ContentPresenter to allow you add content to the already defined layout. Look up the templates for various controls... You can also use Blend to automatically open existing templates or start from scratch plus much more.

Comment: I have finally found the solution using attached properties, and it's quite simple -- just nobody on StackOverflow could point me into that direction. Main post updated.